# Let $f$ be the relation from $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ given by $ f([x])=[x^2+x]$. Prove that $f$ is not a well defined function.

Tags: functions

I am asked to prove the following.

> Let $f$ be the relation from $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ given by $f([x])=[x^2+x]$. Prove that $f$ is not a well defined function.

*Note that [x] and [x^2+x] denote equivalence classes*

I'm familiar with proving statements like this, but I'm unfamiliar with how to disprove the statement above.

If I wish to consider a counterexample, should I consider $[a]\neq[b]$, and then attempt to find a image where $f([a])=f([b])$?

This is homework, so I'd like just a small push.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer the problem statement to run "There is no relation ... such that ..." instead of "Let $f$ be the relation ...", As is, thestatement suggests that there is some object $f$ with the given properties that can be defined, it just lacks the property of being *well* defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, you do what many unexperienced students do: You mix up well-definedness and injectivity.

What you actually have to do here: Find integers, s.t. $[a]=[b]$ (mod 4), but $[a^2+a] \neq [b^2+b]$ (mod 10).

For example we have $[1]=[5]$. So we should have $f([1])=f([5])$. Do we?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure what my textbook was getting at with the statement "If $(a,b),(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$".